# sqlite3 gem on Mac OS X Lion... fail!

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I just upgraded my Mac to Lion but unfortunately I had to re-setup my Rails development environment. With the following versions of software:

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0]
Rails 3.0.9
sqlite3 3.7.5

When I run the command:
    sudo gem install sqlite3

It throws following exception:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb mkmf.rb
```

can't find header files for ruby at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

And the it adds:

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out

Did anyone dive into Lion yet..

Thanks

Comment: At this point in Lion's development, you're much better off taking your question directly to the developers for SQLite3. It's a bit too bleeding edge for StackOverflow right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated Xcode for Mac OS X Lion and sqlite3 gem installed without any trouble... So I think whenever anyone upgrades their Mac OS, the first thing they should do is update Xcode after the upgrade...

Answer (score 6):

I was having problems with this. I downloaded the Xcode from Apps store and it still didn't work. I reinstalled Xcode 3.2 and still nothing. Then I read a post that said that downloading Xcode and installing it were different. I went the Applications and ran the Xcode installer and after that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too and realised installing XCode is not enough, following installation you need to go into XCode -> Preferences -> Download, and install the Command Line Tools.  This installs GCC.

Answer (score 3):

I've always had problems with OS X's built in Ruby. Use RVM. Helps Ruby devs manage their Ruby versions and libraries. Definitely recommended. Then from there, install your gems.

Install Guide: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Edit: You won't even need to sudo anymore since everything is in your home directory hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Xcode didn't do the trick for me.  Instead, I installed [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Then installed sqlite with Homebrew:

```
brew install sqlite
```

And then finally ran:

```
sudo bundle install
```

within my Rails app, which successfully installed Sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to Lion, the first thing I would recommend is downloading and INSTALLING the new Xcode (4.2) from the Apple website. I know this is in regards to rails, but I like having Xcode for messing with Iphone and Ipad applications (granted I'm not very good at it...yet).

Then, you will want to download the GCC installer:

github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads. Download the latest one.

This is somewhat of a replacement for Xcode and it will tell you that you can uninstall Xcode after this install is finished. That's up to you: I did not uninstall Xcode afterwards.

To test it out if it made an impact, I created a rails new appname in my terminal. The bundle worked fine, before it did not. There was an issue with gem install json -v '1.6.5'

Fwiw I'm currently in Chapter 9 of the Hartl tutorial and was working in rails 3.1, Snow Leopard OS X Before today.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to Maverick and had trouble with a few gems.
Go to Apple Developer Downloads and pickup Command Line Tools (OSX Mavericks) for Xcode.
After installation, I was able to bundle sqlite3 and pg gems.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues installing `sqlite3` gem in Mavericks:

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

**xcode-select** manual says, the *reset* option 
`Unsets any user-specified developer directory, so that the developer directory will be found via the default search mechanism.`

By the way, this happened to me while migrating from Snow Leopard to Mavericks. I think the issue was with the developers tool path, which is different in each of these operating systems.